# Why can i not add nu-Get packages in visual studio for Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, nuget, visual-studio-mac

Im creating a system in Unity that requires an API, i'm using visual studio to create my script. I have read instructions adding nu get packages. However i see a-lot of instructions where they add packages in reference however i do not have one. Im using a mac, so where can i find a reference file or do i need to make one.